# Why is 1826 deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

Why is answer [1826](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1826/3487) deleted?

It seems to perfectly answer the question. Source and/or proof of

> Abu Hanifa usually talked opposite of Imam sadiq S.A.

could be exacted. But why delete?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you see that it "perfectly answers the question" since to my eye it barely qualifies as an answer at all.  The second sentence appears to be naught but speculation "**maybe** there is different…," while the "Abu Hanifa usually talked…" is vague and, whether it's true or not, barely supports that speculation.

Remove those two sentences, and it's simply a one-liner that provides a single piece of information supporting a Shi'a ruling (without even providing an actual *ruling*).

And that's not even getting into the fact that the OP isn't explicitly requesting a Shi'a ruling: How useful is it to her, personally, to know the recommendation of Imam Sadiq?

Given that the question is apparently [controversial](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1016/22), providing a single piece of evidence supporting a ruling that the questioner may or may not even be interested in is hardly useful; if the usefulness of an answer can't even be *judged* according to what the questioner is directly asking, either the *question* needs to be clarified, or the *answer* isn't an answer.

As I see it, the post is quite simply an *item*, not an *answer*.  At best, the same information could probably be edited into the [current accepted answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1834/22) on the question, but it hardly has enough content to stand alone.

Could it be fleshed out into a real answer?  Possibly, but given that it would require not only substantial editing but a fundamental change in the *information* presented, it's questionable whether the existing votes would even apply to it; it would be better off just being posted as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question is *So which is the correct way of doing sujood - should I rest my arms or slightly lift them as I recently have been instructed?*

Stating what is recommended by a particular view, along with the source, *answers* the question.

Although the answer was pretty short, wordings could be improvised and more details added, but definitely not worthy of deletion. Could be downvoted (with reason) though.

As stated the source to the claim could be exacted or the matter, irrelevant to the question, removed.

This answer concern revision [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/revisions/1826/1).