# Why my answer to question 1822 is remained undeleted?

Tags: support, moderators, moderation

Many of my answers are being deleted without leaving any comment under them or any notification.

One of them was my answer to [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1822/should-a-womens-arm-rest-in-sujood-prostration/1826#1826). when I accidentally saw it deleted to be honest I considered it low quality and edited it completely. it is completely a new answer. I tried to respect all rules of this site. after improving it and completely renewing it, I flagged it for review and undeleting and I wrote in the flag box:

> the answer was improved. please undelete.

but the result of my flag is amazing to me. this is what I saw as the result of flag:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

This result from moderators seems to me a bit unfair. I really do not understand now what is the problem of this deleted answer. please someone help me to understand what is the problem of my current version of this deleted answer to edit and improve it.

Comment: Uh bro! have some patience! I had an answer deleted and then edited by me and later a mod and undeleted but later the same mod deleted it again!

Comment: @Bludream Bro! this is is only one example of many!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it's now "completely a new answer".  As such, it should probably be posted *as a new answer*, rather than hijacking an old one.

As I explained in [this meta post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1025/22), the work required to make the post constructive would render the existing votes completely useless, since they were *all* cast on the old answer which is substantially different.

Comment: this post does not seem to answer the question. I can post it as new answer. but I am interested to know the reason why my flag was declined and received mentioned result. also it had 0 votes.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala no, it had four votes that added up to 0, which is a significant difference.

Comment: Irrespective of OP stating it to be a completely new answer. It is not. It's an elaboration and improvisation on the previous revision, catering to and addressing the concerns raised [here](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1024/3487). Even if the votes were hijacked on the old one, I don't think it really does, the votes are unlocked anyways. (Un)Deletion and vote hijacking seem to be quite orthogonal issues and shouldn't be mixed.